# Cross network access

Tags: networking, router, remote-access

I have two networks, for now we'll name them "Home" and "Office", it is as set up below:

```
Internet -> Modem -> -> -> -> Router -> -> -> Router
        192.168.2.100      192.168.2.1   WAN 192.168.2.2
    DMZ set to 192.168.2.1                 LAN 10.0.0.1
```

Home network 192.168.2.x

Office network 10.0.0.x

I have some port forwarding set up that work beautifully that allow me to gain access to some web services.  And also thru that, I'm able to remote connect from Home to Office by connecting to 192.168.2.2 with the ports statically pointing to one main server.  My question is, is there a way for me to be able to access one network from another?  For example, I have a printer on the Office network but I'd like to be able to print from the Home network.  Similarly, there may be some network drives in the Office network that I'd like to access from the Home network.  And also, if it is possible, is it always a one-way street, or could I access them both ways.

Comment: Question 1: Is network 2 *behind* network 1, or can the router directly communicate with the modem?

Question 2: Is there a reason you need the two networks, not just one?

Comment: Question 3: Does the modem have multiple Ethernet ports, or does it connect directly to router 1's WAN connection, or what?

Comment: Assuming it's Windows in question, open the ports for File and Print Sharing.

Comment: 1) I don't know what network 1 and 2 are
2) At one point I used this network setup in a landlording situation for a duplex, internet was shared but I didn't want each side to access each other, I've since moved out so now it's become purely academic
3) It connects directly to the WAN of the router

@techie007 Would I then have to port forward those ports, if so which ones?

Comment: This is a scenario that VPNs are perfect for.

Comment: @MaQleod - No, a VPN is an extremely bad way of handling this - any router capable of handling VPN's would be able to handle the routing directly.  Further, within a LAN there is very little to be gained from a VPN, as there is physical control of the network (VPNs are designed to provide security where you don't have physical control), speed slowdowns (due to encryption and decryption), complexity (you still have routing issues to deal with once you break out the VPN) and other gotchas (like MTU/tunneling issues).

Answer (score 1):

You can do (probably - assuming the routers allow it) do this, and you can have access both ways.

The first step is to turn off NAT / address translation on your Office network  (I'm assuming the Office network is 192.168.2.2 / 10.0.0.1).  This will allow your Office network to see your home network based on its real IP, rather then hiding behind the office IP.

The second step is to inform your home router how to reach the office network.  To do this you want to to add a route to 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 with a gateway of 192.168.2.2 - This will inform your home router how to find your office network.  (You don't need to do this on your office network as it should already know how to find the home network as its WAN address is in the home network).

Comment: I'm not sure how to turn off NAT, I looked into it and I saw a lot of correlation with DMZ, and for the most part I'm not using any DMZ, except on the modem, which points to 192.168.2.1 (the only device connected to it), the first router, everything else DMZ is disabled

Comment: Also, I did add the static route to the Home router as you specified and there is no change.  My test for that is to try to remote connect to 10.0.0.20, a computer on the Office network (that I can already connect to by referencing 192.168.2.2 where I port forward port 3389 to it).  However, the other direction works as you mentioned it should, I'm able to access the 192.168.0.x network from the 10.0.0.x network.

Comment: @Cody Thimm what make/models of routers are you using ?  There is no point in adding a static route with NAT on, as the target IP address never sees the source address.

Comment: I'll have to get back to you regarding the model numbers as I'm not there right now (they are both Belkins), but I don't know what "NAT on" means or how to change it.  All I know is I've been told not to use DMZ because it opens up all traffic, bypassing the firewall, which I've been a bigger fan of hardware firewalls vs software.